# Inverse Fourier Transform For Solution Of Diffusion Equation With Convection

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

**My Question:**

How do I complete the inverse Fourier Transform of:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{-k\omega^2t}e^{-ci\omega t}e^{-i\omega x}\,dx$

I cant figure out quite how to use the shift/convolution theorem here.

**The Problem:**

> Solve the diffusion equation with convection:
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^2
>  u}{\partial x^2}+c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, -\infty \lt x \lt
>  \infty$
>
> $\displaystyle u(x,0)=f(x)$

What I have done so far:

$\displaystyle \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right] = k\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right]+c\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]$

...

$\displaystyle \frac{dU}{dt}=-k\omega^2U-ci\omega U$

$\displaystyle \implies U(\omega,t)=C(\omega)e^{-k\omega^2t}e^{-ci\omega t}$

$\displaystyle u(x,0)=f(x)\implies U(\omega,t)=F(\omega)e^{-k\omega^2t}e^{-ci\omega t}$

Let $\displaystyle G(\omega)=e^{-k\omega^2t}e^{-ci\omega t}$, and $H(\omega)=F(\omega)G(\omega)$

Then $U(\omega,t)=H(\omega)$

$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[U(\omega,t)]=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[H(\omega)]$

$\displaystyle \implies u(x,t)=h(x)$

$\displaystyle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)G(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}\,dx$

$\displaystyle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{-k\omega^2t}e^{-ci\omega t}e^{-i\omega x}\,dx$ (Stuck here, when trying to do the inverse....)

Comment: You have $u(x,t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[g(\omega)h(\omega)]$ where $g(\omega)=e^{-k \omega^{2}t}, h(\omega)=f(\omega)e^{-ic\omega t}$. The inverse transform of a _product_ in Fourier space is a _convolution_ in real space. Using that the inverse transforms for $g(\omega), h(\omega)$ are given by [(see table)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms) \begin{align} g(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}e^{-x^{2}/4kt} \\ h(x)&=f(x-ct) \end{align} the solution is then $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left(f(x-ct)*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}e^{-x^{2}/4kt}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u(t, x)$ a solution to the original pde, then define $v(t, x)= e^{-ct}u(t, x)$. Observe
\begin{align}
v_t-k v_{xx} =&\ -ce^{-ct}u(t, x)+e^{ct}u_t(t, x)-ke^{ct}u_{xx}(t, x) \\
=&\ e^{ct}(u_t(t, x)-ku_{xx}(t, x)-cu(t, x)) = 0
\end{align}
which is just the heat equation. Now solve it with Fourier transform or whatever you like. Then we see that
\begin{align}
u(t, x) = e^{ct}v(t, x)
\end{align}
is your solution.